# How to add value in dropdown list in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

let consider multiple dimensional array contains some records and I have two dropdown list
1) list1
2) list2
Now,
I want to add an array values on list2 via changing of list1. If the value of list1 is "-1" then list2 must be remove or hidden. Else empty list2, make it visible and insert values from array in list1. I have done it but there is some queries which i couldn't solve. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.
Here is the code:

```
<select id="list1" onchange="changeVal(this.value);">
   <option value="-1">Select any option</option>
   <option value="0">test1</option>
   <option value="1">test2</option>
   <option value="2">test3</option>
</select>
<select id="list2">
</select>

function changeVal(i){
  var Arr = [
    ['Dummy 1.1','Dummy 1.2','Dummy 1.3'],
    ['Dummy 2.1','Dummy 2.2','Dummy 2.3'],
    ['Dummy 3.1','Dummy 3.2','Dummy 3.3']
];

if(i != "-1"){
    $("#list2").html("");
    $("#list2").css("visibility","visible");
    for (var addOption = 0; addOption < Arr[i].length; addOption++){
        var option = $("<option></option>");
        $("#list2").append(option);
        option.html(Arr[i][addOption]);
    }
}

else{
      $("#list2").remove();
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is `appendSelect` and Where are you using `changeVal()`?

Comment: wait i am editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like following:

```
$('#list1').change(function () {   
var i = $(this).val();
if(i>-1){
  $('#list2').empty();
  $('#list2').show();
  for(var k=0;k<Arr[i].length;k++){
    $('#list2').append(
        $('<option>', {
        value: Arr[i][k],
        text: Arr[i][k]
        }, '<option/>')
    );
  }
}
else{
   $('#list2').hide();
    }
});
```

this fiddle will help you:  http://jsfiddle.net/3nEWg/1/

Comment: First of all, Thanks Azim, it's work and sorry for late reply i was busy in another project.

Answer (score 1):

to append option to select use this

```
 for (var addOption = 0; addOption < Arr[i].length; addOption++) {
            $('#list2').append($('<option>', {
                value: addOption ,
                text: Arr[i][addOption] 
            }));
        }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/A9Q9R/2/)

Comment: as before editing your question , uou were binding select with id appendSelect , but now you are binding list2. so see the updated answer.

Comment: Dear Amit Kumar, I would like to appreciate you and thanks to give your precious time to me.